# How to host an cocos2d-js web only game?

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm very confused. Before I run an simple webonly cocos2d-js example, I was under the impression it generates the html5 + js files so I can host it everywhere or either run offline.

But it is not the case, to run my example locally I have to start an cocos webserver which makes me wonder: Why does it need a webserver to run offline simple html5+js code?  and What Do I need to host an cocos2d-js webonly game(I use IIS)?

Comment: That's because your computer is not a webserver. Only running a webserver service makes it a webserver. Hence for local testing you need to run the webserver app which then hosts the js content that your browser can open, download and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion comes from your assumption that just because something is HTML5 and javascript, it should be able to run locally.

That isn't always true.

There are many HTML5 features that require a webserver -- mostly for security reasons.  One in particular is XMLHttpRequest which Cocos uses to load asset libraries asynchronously.  For security reasons, XMLHttpRequest does not run locally unless you use a local webserver.

Comment: that makes sense but how does it know which webserver should run it? Do all webservers by default implement the XMLHttpRequest in order the cocos2d-js run? Can I assume ANY webserver would be able to host and allow client to run games without any difference/issues between them?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a client-side concept rather than a server-side one. An XMLHttpRequest issues an ordinary HTTP request to the server, much as a web browser would. Any webserver that can serve content should be able to respond to an XMLHttpRequest (although the specific server response will depend on the request itself).

Comment: When I say 'much as a web browser would', I mean 'as a web browser would if you entered a URL and hit GO'. A web browser is what actually makes the request when XMLHttpRequest is used (because the XMLHttpRequest is in Javascript in the browser, on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of security reasons, to prevent malicious scripts accessing local files.

This can be bypassed in Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option, but it is still not recommended.

Using a local webserver is indeed the best solution.